# Safari audio file duration = infinity – how to fix?

Tags: audio, safari, header, range

I have the following problem which drives me crazy:

I play an audio file on a webpage:

```
<audio ref="audio" preload="metadata" class="AudioPlayer__audio">
  <source src="file" type="audio/mp3" codecs="mp3">
  <p>Your browser doesn't support HTML5 audio. Here is a <a href="file.mp3">link to the audio</a> instead.</p>
</audio>
```

I have built a custom timeline which needs to know the duration of the file.
Now this works fine except if I deploy it.

On my remote the duration of the audio file is `infinity`.
Obviously and how I read in other threads this is due to the fact that Safari makes two requests:
The first one just trying to get some bytes. `Range: bytes=0-1`
This request fails.
After that Safari makes another request trying to get the file without the range stuff, which succeeds, but somehow the audio duration is `infinity`.

I read stuff about Headers and that the must allow ranges, but I don't really know much about Headers and how to fix this specific issue.

[image]

Here you can see the request and the response.
It seems to me that range is allowed because I see:
`Accept-Ranges: bytes`

What else am I missing, and how would I even make changes to those headers?
The response header probably would need some changes on my netlify settings,
but what about my request headers? And is this even the problem?
I have no real clue where I could go on debugging this issue.

thanks for any pointers.

Cheers

Comment: Did you find a fix for this?

Comment: I don't know anymore. I somehow got the project to run but no idea if I solved this problem or if I found a way around it. I would have to dig deeply into my code and commits from back then. If I have time I can try to find out, but right now I can't promise anything.